# AWS ECS service discovery resolves the wrong IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a Backend Service running in ECS. It used to work normally, but I just deployed a new version and now there is a problem.

I'm using AWS Service discovery

There is a reverse proxy service which is supposed to forward requests to the backend service.
However, it seems the the service discovery resolves the name to the wrong IP!

```
connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.1.48, server: , request: "GET /api/user/health HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.0.161:7845/api/user/health", host: "some_aws_host"
```

The private IP of my service is not 10.0.0.161, but it's 10.0.0.168 according to ECS console.

The API service (reverse proxy) is passing requests like this:

```
  location /api/user/ {
        
      if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)$) {
        return 405;
      }

      proxy_pass http://user-service.service-discovery-ep.local:9000/api/user/; 
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

This used to work fine just 1 hour ago. How can I fix this? I mean, it seems AWS discovery returns the wrong ip... What can I do about that?

Comment: I think this is down to NGINX not re-resolving the hostname. You can fix that by using a variable in `proxy_pass`. There's a cross site duplicate of this at https://serverfault.com/a/593003/246902